# Jquery added form fields populate on edit form

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have in my form in add.ctp some dynamic fields inserted with Jquery. This works OK, data is stored in database. But problem is with edit form in edit.ctp. Because dynamic added fields isn't populate with data from database. I'm using CakePHP 2.4.1 and Jquery 1.7.2. So my question is how to populate table Users in edit.ctp with related data from database? I cant'find any tutorial for this. Could you help me please? My code:

```
/* Groups/add.ctp and Groups/edit.ctp */

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Group');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Group'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
?>
</fieldset>
<h2>Users</h2>
<table id="mytable">
<tr><th></th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>
<tr id="user0" style="display:none;">
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this user')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.lastName',array('label'=>'','type'=>'text')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.firstName',array('label'=>'','type'=>'text')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.email',array('label'=>'','type'=>'text')); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr id="trAdd"><td> <?php echo $this->Form->button('+',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to add another user','onclick'=>'addUser()')); ?> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>

/* Javascript */

<script type='text/javascript'>
var lastRow=0;

function addUser() {
    lastRow++;
    $("#mytable tbody>tr:#user0").clone(true).attr('id','user'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr:#trAdd");
    $("#user"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeUser('+lastRow+')');
    $("#user"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('name','data[User]['+lastRow+'][lastName]').attr('id','userLastName'+lastRow);
    $("#user"+lastRow+" input:eq(1)").attr('name','data[User]['+lastRow+'][firstName]').attr('id','userFirstName'+lastRow);
    $("#user"+lastRow+" input:eq(2)").attr('name','data[User]['+lastRow+'][email]').attr('id','userEmail'+lastRow);
}

function removeUser(x) {
    $("#user"+x).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting the fields from the edit form, you can retrieve the values with

```
$this->Form->value(Model.fieldname);
```

Comment: No, I want be able to edit Users in Group/edit.ctp. When I click on Edit Group, I want to see Users table with Users related to this Group. Now I see Users table in Group/edit.ctp but without related Users data. Do you understand me?